# Ambiguous Columns and Count

Tags: sql, sqlite, db-browser-sqlite

My query requires me to find the busiest location by number of people (Schema Attached)[image: Tracking]

```
select DISTINCT location.name as 'Location', f_name|| ' ' || l_name as 'Citizen'
from CheckIn
join location on checkin.LocID = Location.LocID
join  person on person.PersonID = CheckIn.PersonID
```

With the above query. I can find the people who visited the locations but I cannot find the most number of people who visited a location as they all show individually. I know I need to add a count or group by.

If I try to put the count as per below

```
select DISTINCT location.name as 'Location', f_name|| ' ' || l_name as 'Citizen', count (personid)
from CheckIn
join location on checkin.LocID = Location.LocID
join  person on person.PersonID = CheckIn.PersonID
```

It will show me ambiguous column. I know it is saying that because I have used it as a join but then how do I count the persons If I cannot reuse it?

How do I fix this code to show me the busiest location by number of people?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT LID, COUNT(*) 
FROM CheckIn
GROUP BY LID
```

returns the number of people visited each `LID`.
You can also use window function `RANK()` to rank each location by the number of people:

```
SELECT LID, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rnk 
FROM CheckIn
GROUP BY LID
```

Finally you use this query with the operator `IN` to return the details of the locations ranked first:

```
SELECT * FROM Location 
WHERE LocationID IN (
  SELECT LID
  FROM (
    SELECT LID, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rnk 
    FROM CheckIn
    GROUP BY LID
  )
  WHERE rnk = 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below:

```
select 
  name, COUNT(P.PersonID) as People_Count
from Location AS L
inner join checkin as C on C.LocID = L.LocID
inner join  person as P on P.PersonID = C.PersonID
group by name
order by COUNT(P.PersonID) desc
```